# how to tune actionbarsherlock for android studio

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio

I'm getting an error when trying to use actionbarsherlock

```
Could not find com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.5.
```

used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) while configuring ABS in android studio..

UPDATE:

while compiling I get the following error messages:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock:compileReleaseAidl'.
> tried to access class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask$DepFileProcessor from class com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DependencyBasedCompileTask
```

UPDATE: 
BuildGradle  file for ActionBarSherlock/actionbarsherlock:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

  sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
      instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
  }
}
```